# Get the rolling sum of cost for last 2 years on specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I have to rolling sum of last 2 year actual margin/revenue for particular month.

Let's say for example the month & year of invoice is July 2019. I will need to get the `SUM(ActualMargin)` from July 2017 to 2019.

Does the `OVER()` function work here?

This is my previous query:

```
SELECT Agent AS IBO,
  CustomerMode AS Mode,
  MONTH(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate) AS monthInvoice,
  YEAR(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate) AS yearInvoice,
  SUM(ActualMargin) AS ActualMargin,
  SUM(TotalActualRevenue) AS TotalActualRevenue,
  (SUM(ActualMargin) / NULLIF(SUM(TotalActualRevenue), 0)) * 100 AS MarginPct
FROM table
GROUP BY Agent, CustomerMode, MONTH(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate), YEAR(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate)
ORDER BY Agent, CustomerMode
```

Final output would be for a Agent - Mode combination, I should get `SUM(Actual Margin)` where summing up the actual margin until the last 24 months from the present month.

[For a IBO, Mode combo, Monthinvoice, YearInvoice combo - need the sum of actual margin for last 24 months. For eg, DALLAS_CMO - LTL - June 2016 should fetch me sum(Actual Margin) as the total of all Actual Margin from June 2014 until June 2016)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCXJe.png)

Comment: Your DBMS is MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @AlessioCantarella SQL Server. I'm using MSFT SQL Server Mgmt Studio

Comment: Why the MySQL tag then, or talking about MySQL in the question? This won't help at all as MySQL first added windowing support in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos removed

Comment: add some sample input and expected output..

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want this by agent and customermode?  They are not mentioned in the question but seem important in the query.  Do you have data for all months?

Answer (score 0):

Over should work for you as long as you are on a suitable version of SQL Server.

Below is a version of your query with a column (ActualMargin2Years) added for the sum of actual margin over the past two years. Note that I'm going back 23 months which makes a 24 month window including the current month. If as you state you want to go from July 2017 to July 2019 that's actually 25 months as the period will include July 2017, 2018 and 2019.

```
SELECT Agent AS IBO,
  CustomerMode AS Mode,
  MONTH(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate) AS monthInvoice,
  YEAR(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate) AS yearInvoice,
  SUM(ActualMargin) AS ActualMargin,
  SUM(SUM(ActualMargin)) OVER (PARTITION BY Agent,CustomerMode ORDER BY YEAR(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate),MONTH(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate)  rows between 23 preceding an current row) AS ActualMargin2Years,
  SUM(TotalActualRevenue) AS TotalActualRevenue,
  (SUM(ActualMargin) / NULLIF(SUM(TotalActualRevenue), 0)) * 100 AS MarginPct
FROM table
GROUP BY Agent, CustomerMode, MONTH(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate), YEAR(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate)
ORDER BY Agent, CustomerMode
```

If you need a different window to aggregate over the following might be appropriate alternatives.
25 month window including the current month:

```
rows between current row and 24 preceding
```

24 month window excluding the current month:

```
rows between 1 preceeding and 23 preceding
```

Comment: Getting this error when i run this code "ActualMargin is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: Ooops, I always forget that when you're calling a window aggregate on top of a grouped aggregate you SUM the SUM. I've made a fix.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want get **Cumulative Margin** with combination key `Agent` and `CustomerMode`, in that case you may try as follows:

```
select  t.IBO,
        t.Mode,
        yearInvoice,
        monthInvoice,
        SUM (ActualMargin) over (partition by t.IBO, t.Mode order by yearInvoice, monthInvoice) as CumulativeMargin
from (
    SELECT    Agent AS IBO,
              CustomerMode AS Mode,
              MONTH(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate) AS monthInvoice,
              YEAR(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate) AS yearInvoice,
              SUM(ActualMargin) AS ActualMargin,
              SUM(TotalActualRevenue) AS TotalActualRevenue,
              (SUM(ActualMargin) / NULLIF(SUM(TotalActualRevenue), 0)) * 100 AS MarginPct
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Agent, CustomerMode, MONTH(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate), YEAR(OriginalInvoiceExtractDate)
    ) as t 
go
```